# Writing Proof Examples

Tags: proof-writing

What are examples of magic mountain an circle diagram proofs for 2nd - 5th grade math problems? I want to teach how to prove word problem outcomes of addition and subtraction.

Comment: What are "magic mountain an circle diagram proofs"?

Comment: That was really my question.  I have figured out what magic mountain is, I think, but am not sure of circle diagram proofs.  Magic mountains are number bond diagrams, right?